# Scatter Plot between 2 images Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, scatterplot

I have 2 high-resolution images in Google Earth Engine. I want to plot a scatter between these 2 images. But I am getting some error `Missing required arguments to function seriesByRegion(): reducer`. I don't know how to correct this (or if this is due to the images).

First I imported geometry and my Image:

```
var RZSC = ee.Image("users/chandrakant/Max_RZSC_Layer_Trail_3"),
    geometry = /* color: #d6cbbb */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-81.375, -56.125],
          [-34.625, -56.125],
          [-34.625, 12.625],
          [-81.375, 12.625]]]);
```

Then I visulatized the Image

```
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['b1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1500.0,
  palette: ['blue', 'green', 'red']
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 10);
Map.addLayer(RZSC.clip(geometry), vizParams, 'Rootzone Storage Capacity');
Map.centerObject(RZSC);
print('RZSC Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', RZSC.projection());
```

Visualized my MODIS image

```
var MODIStc = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/051/MOD44B')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2017-12-01')).mean();
var percentTreeCover = MODIStc.select('Percent_Tree_Cover');
var percentTreeCoverVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['bbe029', '0a9501', '074b03'],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
Map.addLayer(percentTreeCover.clip(geometry), percentTreeCoverVis, 'Percent Tree Cover');
print('MOD44B Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', percentTreeCover.projection());
\\Here I added Water Mask
var waterOcc = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater").select('occurrence'),
    jrc_data0 = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_0/Metadata").select('total_obs').lte(0),
    waterOccFilled = waterOcc.unmask(0).max(jrc_data0),
    waterMask = waterOccFilled.lt(50);
```

Here I reprojected the image (RZSC) at 250 m

```
\\Here I tried to increase the resolution from 25km to 250m    
var RZSC_250m = RZSC.resample('bilinear').reproject({
  crs: RZSC.projection().crs(),
  scale: 250
});
Map.addLayer(RZSC_250m.clip(geometry).updateMask(waterMask), vizParams, 'RZSC_250m');
print('RZSC_250m Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', RZSC_250m.projection());
```

[image]

Tried a scatterplot here

```
\\Tried to plot scatterplot here (I want just the basic scatter plot between 2 variables)
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(RZSC, MODIStc, 
                ee.Reducer.mean(),250, 'nd').setChartType('ScatterChart');
print(chart);
```

**The error I get:**
`Error generating chart: Collection.map, argument 'collection': Invalid type. Expected: FeatureCollection. Actual: Image<[Percent_Tree_Cover]>.`
and `Collection.map, argument 'collection': Invalid type. Expected: FeatureCollection. Actual: Image<[Percent_Tree_Cover]>.`

**Additional information:**
Also, I don't know why, but the dimensions of `MODIStc` and `RZSC_250m` are different.
For MODIStc:

```
bands: List (1 element)
0: "Percent_Tree_Cover", double ∈ [0, 255], EPSG:4326, 48x73 px
id: Percent_Tree_Cover
crs: EPSG:4326
crs_transform: [1,0,0,0,1,0]
data_type: double ∈ [0, 255]
dimensions: [48,73]
origin: [-82,-59]
```

For RZSC_250m:

```
bands: List (1 element)
0: "b1", float, EPSG:4326, 20818x28371 px
id: b1
crs: EPSG:4326
crs_transform: List (6 elements)
data_type: float
dimensions: [20818,28371]
origin: [-36235,-6107]
```

Also, when I try to use `reproject` on MODIStc, the data looks smoothed and weird (a lot of details are lost).
[image]